# How to define type of interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I want to write a function that modifies values of a form with a certain interface. Then I get the error that string is not part of the form interface keys. How can I define a type for that function? Why can't I use the interface as type?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-typescript-forked-9g7pb)

```
interface IForm {
   age: number
   name: string
   job: string
}
```

// ts error: cannot assign string to "age" | "name" | "job"

```
const setCustom = value => setValue(value, "")
```

//no ts error

```
const setCustom: (value: "age" | "name" | "job") => void = value => setValue(value, "")
```

Comment: What is `setValue`?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/ymAeQm) which demonstrates your issue and where the only issue present is the one you're asking about.  Right now I don't understand where the error is coming from, nor do I understand what you mean by "use the interface as type"; presumably to use the interface as a type you would mention the interface somewhere in the code you have an issue with.

Comment: @jcalz I added a sandbox link. The you will finde the function setCustom. I want to make a typed function, so that the parameter is not any.

Comment: Does `const setCustom = (a: keyof FormData) => setValue(a, "")` work for you?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @jcalz that is what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the [`keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) which takes an object type like `IForm` and produces a union of its keys:

```
type KeyofIform = keyof IForm;
// type KeyofIform = "age" | "name" | "job"
```

So anywhere you were manually specifying `"age" | "name" | "job"` you can instead use `keyof IForm`, which is equivalent and will automatically change if `IForm`'s definition changes:

```
const setCustom: (value: keyof IForm) => void = value => setValue(value, "")
// const setCustom: (value: keyof IForm) => void

setCustom("age"); // okay
setCustom("name"); // okay
setCustom("job"); // okay
setCustom("shoeSize"); // error!
// Argument of type '"shoeSize"' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '"age" | "name" | "job"'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2UC2yDeAUMsnAOYQBcyIArjgEbTE1w5XIDOYUoZLAK0wNq3XiH4BfQoTABPAA4oA0hDmYYqGNjwBeZAGs1GtFlwBuQgHoryeUuSr1m7bmT6AROQgfkAH2QPEDYff0ChBg8ZABMIBAAbOCgUBEwQbi4IMAA1OHjaDgAKAA9qOBA5ABpkOTKKgEp3AD5SCsJU9LBMsABhWm5MHGpCgDc8guojZ1MdRt0WkcxgaPdkMfyUee7cjdHxiGqPD3rrWw6Mziy+gaHkPY3J4xgZ3DmFpeiZS97+sEHCrwUY7mZA2ZCYAxwOSEb7XP44AHBdjA0G2CFQmFXX7-DwRFFg9HQ2HYhEeTgAC0wEAAysAAF4+eogsHQKDYACEp2QAEEoGR6BBwODnvYUAByMmUmn0nxi5DATg0TBdOCcTjAMjBBjxFB-ZAKJIhSBQYV2RTiwGhAJBEK+a14sVAA)

Answer (score -2):

You need to put ; at the end of each variable:

```
interface IForm {
   age?: number;
   name?: string;
   job?: string;
}
```

Comment: Not adding the delimiter is valid: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2UC2yDeAsAFDJlwDmEAXMiAK44BG0JZdcONyAzmFKApsyAK0xNafASCHEAviRIJMIPsgAetDNjwBeAsPJVaAZgA0HLrQBE6KBAAm1i2InJrAFQhwADpjDIDhA8wBQg0NYkckA)

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect (you do not need to put `;` in properties) and does not seem to address the issue in the question.  I suggest you edit or delete it.

Comment: depends on your [prettier](https://prettier.io/) settings

Comment: Nope, Java technology ASI (automatic semicolon insertion) works in ES, so in TS too